# Hibernate: can not resolve symbol beginTransaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have created this hibernate configuration class in my demo project

```
mport org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
//        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Then I try to start the session from Customer class

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

but I get this error

```
can not resolve symbol beginTransaction
```

What am I missing here?